# converting the lines of the file into a tuple of list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

In my python file:

- the first line contains : `10`
- the second line : `a7,j7,d10,g10`
- the third line : `d1,g1,a4,j4`
- fourth line : `a3,b3,c3,d3,e3` but can be empty.

And I would like to convert it into this in python 3:

```
([10], ['a7','j7','d10','g10'], ['d1','g1','a4','j4'], ['a3','b3','c3','d3','e3'])
```

But the last line `['a3','b3','c3','d3','e3']` can return an empty list if there isn't a fourth line.

I have opened the file but can't convert it into a tuple of lists.

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you please share your code, so we can improve it.

Comment: it's for a school project I can't share it anywhere sorry

Answer (score 2):

```sh
$ echo "10
a7,j7,d10,g10
d1,g1,a4,j4
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3" > my_file.txt

$ echo "10
a7,j7,d10,g10
d1,g1,a4,j4
" > my_file2.txt
```

You can use a comprehension to process each line of the file, and feed that to `tuple()`. In this case, it looks like what you want to do is split each line on the comma (turning the one comma-separated string that is each line, into a list of strings without commas), but if the line is empty or contains only whitespace, add an empty list instead.

```
def process_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        return tuple(
            line.strip().split(',') if line.strip() else [] 
            for line in infile
        )

process_file('my_file.txt')
# (['10'], ['a7', 'j7', 'd10', 'g10'], ['d1', 'g1', 'a4', 'j4'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3'])

process_file('my_file2.txt')
# (['10'], ['a7', 'j7', 'd10', 'g10'], ['d1', 'g1', 'a4', 'j4'], [])
```

If you wanted to omit the empty list entirely if the line is blank, then you can move the condition `if line.strip()` to after `for line in infile`, and remove the `else` clause. This will cause the comprehension to just ignore empty lines, not adding anything to the tuple for them.

Comment: Thank You for you help